# Como enviar/receber dados usando Sendmessage ou Postmessage API?

Tags: delphi, windows, winapi

Preciso enviar vários dados para outro processo, o detalhe e os dois processos são dlls, e customizei minha mensagem. A mensagem consigo enviar e recebe-la mas ao tentar tratar os dados vindo por `WParam` da acesso violado.

A minha estrutura de dados seria essa:

```
type
  TMyStruct = packed record
    lpHandle: HWND;
    lpProcessid: DWORD;
  end;

var
  MyData: TMyStruct;

MyData.lpHandle:= handleprocess;
MyData.lpProcessid:= GetCurrentThreadId;
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SHUTDOWN_THREADS, 0, LongInt(@MyData));
```

Oa receber:

```
type
  PMyStruct=^TMyStruct;
  TMyStruct = packed record
    lpHandle: HWND;
    lpProcessid: DWORD;
  end;

procedure TWinProc.WndProcedure(var _msg: TMessage);
var
  MyStruct: PMyStruct;
begin
  if _msg.Msg = WM_SHUTDOWN_THREADS then
  begin
    MyStruct:= PMyStruct(_msg.LParam);
    if (MyStruct^.lpBrowser = 0) then
      TerminaProcesso(MyStruct^.lpProcid)
    else
    if (not IsWindow(Wndthread)) then
    begin
      Fhandle:= MyStruct^.lpHandle;
      Wndthread:= CreateThread(nil, 0, @CallProcedure, nil, 0, WndthreadID);
    end;
  end
  else
    _msg.Result:= DefWindowProc(WinProc.WndProcHandle, _msg.Msg, _msg.WParam, _msg.LParam);
end;
```

Se alguém sabe como posso corrigir essa comunicação serei grato.

Comment: Quem envia e quem recebe são processos diferentes? Se sim, aí esta sua explicação. Vocẽ esta enviando um endereço no parâmetro `LongInt(@MyData)`, que é inválido para o processo que recebe a mensagem. Acredito que esta forma de IPC não suporte dados de tamanhos arbitrários.

Comment: Obrigado por responder... e sim sao processos diferentes, cada processo carrega uma dll diferente e gostaria que elas se comunicassem. Qual a solucao para isso ?

Comment: Utilize um socket ou um named pipe. Named pipe são mais rápidos do que sockets, mas geralmente o pessoal se sente mais confortável com socket. Não encontrei um tutorial acessível em Delphi, mas encontrei um em C++, facilmente traduzível para Delphi: http://avid-insight.co.uk/2012/03/introduction-to-win32-named-pipes-cpp/

Answer (score 3):

Você está passando os dados através de [*lParam*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(VS.85).aspx), *wParam* chega ao outro processo vazio.

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SHUTDOWN_THREADS, 0, LongInt(@MyData));
                                                 ↑
```

Se entendi o que queres fazer, você terá um problema com o código atual, pois ele está tentando passar o endereço de uma estrutura para outro processo, um endereço só têm significado dentro de um único processo.

Porque um processo é um conjunto de segmentos, todos rodando em um único espaço de endereço, cada processo tem ao menos um segmento, o segmento principal. Somente segmentos do mesmo processo podem fazer a *partilha* de recursos, como acessar qualquer endereço válido no [espaço de endereço do processo](http://groups.ist.utl.pt/~leic-so.daemon/2011-2012/teoricas_alameda/05a%20-%20gestao%20de%20memoria%20-%20mecanismos.pdf).

Você pode fazer o que o [Vinícius Gobbo A. de Oliveira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14650/vin%C3%ADcius-gobbo-a-de-oliveira) [disse em comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49491/como-enviar-receber-dados-usando-sendmessage-ou-postmessage-api#comment101144_49491), utilizar [*named pipes*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [**Aqui**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/852750/NET-and-Delphi-Inter-Process-Communication-via-Nam) têm um artigo que explica sobre a [comunicação entre processos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_entre_processos) por meio de *named pipes*, aplicável para Delphi e .NET.

Uma alternativa é [mapear o arquivo em memória](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx) utilizando as funções [`CreateFileMapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) para criar o mapeamento, [`OpenFileMapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) para abrir o arquivo e [`MapViewOfFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) para ler o conteúdo do arquivo.

Uma outra alternativa (*um pouco mais simples*) que pode ser utilizada é o recurso de Cópia de Dados([**Data Copy**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648710(v=vs.85).aspx)) que permite enviar dados de uma aplicação a outra.

Para usa-la você terá que enviar a mensagem [`WM_COPYDATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011(v=vs.85).aspx) através da função  [`PostMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ou [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx)(para enviar para um segmento do mesmo processo pode ser usado [`PostThreadMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx), *mas não é esse o caso!*).

Os dados devem ser passados para uma estrutura [`COPYDATASTRUCT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649010(v=vs.85).aspx).

O exemplo abaixo vai enviar uma estrutura que vai conter a *Handle* e o *PID* do processo que enviará a mensagem.

```pascal
type
  TMyStruct = packed record  // Estrutura que vai ser enviada a outro processo
    lpHandle: HWND;
    lpProcessid: DWORD;
end;

procedure PostData;   // Método responsável por enviar
var
  H: HWND;
  MyStruct: TMyStruct;
  copyDataStruct: TCopyDataStruct;
Begin
Try
  MyStruct.lpHandle := Application.Handle;       // Pega a handle da aplicação
  MyStruct.lpProcessid := GetCurrentProcessId(); // Pega o PID

  copyDataStruct.cbData := SizeOf(MyStruct);     // Tamanho em bytes dos dados apontados em lpdata
  copyDataStruct.lpData := @MyStruct;            // Dados que serão enviados a outro processo

  H := FindWindow(nil, 'Form2');                 // Pega a handle da janela que tenha o Form2 no título
  if IsWindow(h) then                            // Se for uma janela existente
    SendMessage(h, WM_COPYDATA, 0, Integer(@copyDataStruct)); // Envia a mensagem
Except
End;
end;
```

Para receber a mensagem (aplicação que irá receber):

```pascal
type
  TMyStruct = packed record   // Estrutura que vai receber os dados do outro processo
    lpHandle: HWND;
    lpProcessid: DWORD;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    protected
     procedure WMCopyData(var Msg : TWMCopyData); message WM_COPYDATA; // Quando a aplicativo receber essa mensagem
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
// .....
procedure TForm1.WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData); // Método que vai tratar a mensagem WM_COPYDATA
var
  MyStruct: TMyStruct;
  TempHandle, TempProcessID: string;
Begin
  MyStruct := TMyStruct(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData^); // Coloca em MyStruct o que foi recebido
  TempHandle := Inttostr (MyStruct.lpHandle);        // Coloca em TempHandle a handle recebida de outro proceso
  TempProcessID := Inttostr( MyStruct.lpProcessid);  // Coloca em TempProcessID o PID do outro processo

  // Daqui em diante fazer algo...
  ShowMessage(Format('Dados do outro processo:'#13'Handle %s ProcessID %s', [TempHandle, TempProcessID]));
end;
```

O exemplo acima foi feito com formulários, algumas coisas não vão funcionar para um aplicativo *console* ou para uma *DLL*, você terá que adaptar de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Tem um bom artigo que explica sobre isto em:

- [How to Send Information (String, Image, Record) Between Two Applications](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/wm_copydata.htm)